# Converting to MYSQLI from MYSQL... Broken escape function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've spent five hours on this same problem, getting too frustrated to think it through properly, some help would be appreciated.

File include structure is kind  of like:

*page.php* includes-> *head.php* includes->(*glo_functions.php* then *sql_functions.php*)

The line in page.php causing triggering the error:

```
$logdata = $db->escape($_POST['logdata']);
```

Connection made, in file like: globals.php:

```
$db->connect();
```

The escape() function, in file like: sql_functions.php

```
function escape($text) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection_id, '$text');
}
```

The problem (anywhere that calls the function):

```
function log_add($text)
{
    global $db, $row;
    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $text= $db->escape($text);
    $db->query("INSERT INTO log VALUES(NULL, {$row['userid']}, unix_timestamp(), '$text', '$IP')");
}
```

Many errors have happened. If connection_id and $text are in reverse it says it expects parameter 1 and kills the script.

Ideally there will be a way for the escape function to sanitize the information somehow. After this has been execute, as of now, my log table is being populated with $text and not the actual text.

I understand preparing queries would be a better option but would take a lot more than 5 hours to do that with every query. I'm converting from SQL, therefore data is universally escaped when needed by calling the function, therefore everywhere where data needs escaped, it is calling to this function already.

Edited:

```
$db=new database;
$db->configure($_CONFIG['hostname'],
 $_CONFIG['username'],
 $_CONFIG['password'],
 $_CONFIG['database'],
 $_CONFIG['persistent']);
$db->connect();
```

Comment: Can you paste the code Thai initializes the global $db?

Comment: It's populating with `$text` because you have to use double-quotes around variables, not single quotes.  If `$text = "something"`, then `'$text' == "$text"` but `"$text" == "something"` .

Comment: Don't use escaping like this. Just use parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this. You should do everything you can to not have any `$` variables in your query string.

Comment: Change `'$text'` to `$text` - remove the quotes.

Comment: @halfer That is just a gramatical error. I can assure its consistent in the code.

Comment: @tadman that would mean re-writing thousands of queries accross hundreds of files. repairing this function to work with mysqli is the most realistic option

Comment: @user3147145 You're going to have to do it anyway to be sure your application isn't full of gaping [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you miss even **one** escaping operation, you're done, you can be cracked wide open. What you're essentially saying is your application has a lot of [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection_id, '$text');
```

You put the variable inside single-quotes, so it will use the literal string "$text", not the value of a variable $text.

You could use double-quotes to ensure the variable is expanded:

```
return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection_id, "$text");
```

Or else just don't put it in quotes at all for this case. Passing a variable to a PHP function is not SQL injection.

```
return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection_id, $text);
```

Of course when you use a variable inside a string literal in an SQL query, you do need to delimit it with single-quotes.

I agree with other commenters that using query parameters is superior, if only because you never have to worry about quotes again. But I understand that you have to forego that code update for now.

Comment: Absoloutly correct. I made this mistake as the old mysql real escape string worked correctly like:`return mysql_real_escape_string('text', $this->connection_id);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function escape($text) {
  global $link; // link to db
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $text);
}
```

Or

```
function escape($text) {
  global $db; // db object
  return $db->real_escape_string($text);
}
```

or only if `escape` is a method of the same class where you create your `$db` object:

```
function escape($text) {
  return $this->mysqli_real_escape_string($text);
}
```

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli`

Comment: @user3147145 You need the *actual* db link in place of `$link` above.

Comment: Quote "if escape is a method of the same class where you create your $db object:". This is the case. Thank you for your help.